# HIVE correlations with corr are not correct

Tags: azure, hadoop, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to correlate two rows in HIVE using "corr". Unfortunately the results are completely wrong. If I use the PIG function the results are OK.

I have checked the options in both HDInsight and a spreadsheet.

Also when I run the same query in HortonsSandbox the results are correct. Something must be wrong in the HDInsight implementation.
The query is straight forward:

```
select x, corr( z,y) from myTable group by x;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3455

Comment: Yes could be. The funny thing, if I take a subset of the data and run the corr on HDInsight and in the HortonWorks Sandbox, the HDInsight is way off and the Sandbox is correct on in as many digits I can see? So the bug must be corrected by Horton and not in HDInsight.